# TYPO3 6.2 - 404 error page with realurl

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

I've a TYPO3 CMS 6.2.15 running with realurl and the following LocalConfiguration.php:

```
'FE' => array(
    'pageNotFound_handling' => '/404/',
    'pageNotFound_handling_statheader' => "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found",
    ...
), ...
```

I've created a page called "404" and tested if I can call that page like *page.ending/404/*. It works. But now I try a non-existing page like *page.ending/asdfasdf/* and get the default Apache `Unauthorized` page. Why is that?

At least I get the correct 404 header information but why does it not redirect to the 404 page?

Comment: Have you tried to enter the full url "http://page.ending/404/" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the corresponding line to:

```
'pageNotFound_handling' => 'REDIRECT:<your-404-url>',
```

Comment: `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = 'REDIRECT:/your-relative-404-url/';`

Answer (score 0):

First check php function `curl` is enable or not in your `php.ini` file. if `curl` is disable then first enable this function.

Then use below code in your `LocalConfiguration.php` file.

```
'FE' => [
    'pageNotFound_handling' => '/your-page-name/',
],
```